# Cómo modificar estilos de Material UI desde SASS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, material-ui

Estoy probando a modificar Material UI desde SASS, para un miniproyectito que estoy haciendo con React y JavaScript. Sin embargo, me están apareciendo errores. Os enseño mi componente Button y su SCSS:

```
    // import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import "./CustomButton.scss";

function CustomButton() {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      className="buttom primary-buttom"
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  );
}

export default CustomButton;
```

Y el código de SCSS:

```
@import "@material-ui/core/Button";
```

Básicamente, tengo esto así porque debería de renderizar. Sin embargo, no renderiza y da error porque dice que en el import del SCSS no sabe de dónde importar. He visto en un tutorial que hace dos años esta forma funcionaba, sin embargo parece que a día de hoy esta forma no funciona e incluso no sé si es posible.
La idea básica es mediante la vinculación del componente de Material UI a mi fichero SCSS poder personalizar el botón de forma limpia. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada Material UI es un framework de componentes no de styles, trabaja con su propio procesador de Styles [Documentación de MakeStyles](https://material-ui.com/es/styles/basics/)

Si necesitas ocupar SCSS lo mejor sería que hicieras un archivo y llamaras a la clase en tu componente por ejemplo [CSS plano en Material UI](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#plain-css)

Por cierto en este bloque `@import "@material-ui/core/Button"` no puedes importar el "CSS" de ese componente así, ya que es JSX no CSS.

En el siguiente bloque debes importar el componente Button.

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import "./CustomButton.scss";

function CustomButton() {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      className="buttom primary-buttom"
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  );
}

export default CustomButton;
```

Para tu SCSS en el archivo CustomButton.scss este podría ser un ejemplo

```
.button{
   color: blue;
}

.primary-button{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Es totalmente valido llamar las clases desde el componente y agregarlas al className